# Pygame: why the eraser tool doesn't work like intended?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to build a basic pixel art editor, and currently struggling hard with finding the error in my code. The pencil works good, but the eraser doesn't.

**Sample showing what's going on:**
[image]

#### Main file

```
import pygame as pg
from settings import *
from gui import *
from canvas import Canvas
from utils import Tools

from os import path
import sys

class Pyxel:

    def __init__(self, tile_size: int):
        pg.init()

        # Main screen
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        #
        pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        pg.key.set_repeat(500, 100)
        self.load_data()
        
        
        self.tile_size = tile_size

    def load_data(self):
        game_folder = path.dirname(__file__)
        img_folder = path.join(game_folder, 'img')
        font_folder = path.join(game_folder, 'fonts')

        self.pencil_icon = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, PENCIL_ICON)).convert_alpha()
        self.pencil_icon_hover = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, PENCIL_HOVER)).convert_alpha()
        self.pencil_icon_clicked = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, PENCIL_CLICKED)).convert_alpha()
        self.eraser_icon = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, ERASER_ICON)).convert_alpha()
        self.eraser_icon_hover = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, ERASER_HOVER)).convert_alpha()
        self.eraser_icon_clicked = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, ERASER_CLICKED)).convert_alpha()

    def new(self):
        """ Initialize variables and do the initial setup """

        self.canvas = Canvas(self)
        self.gui = GUI(self)
        self.tool_buttons = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.load_toolbtns()
        self.selected_tool = self.pencil_tool
        self.selected_tool.clicked = True
        self.selected_color = BLACK
        self.canvas_grid = []
        for x in range(0, self.tile_size):
            self.canvas_grid.append([])
            for y in range(0, self.tile_size):
                self.canvas_grid[x].append({"color":None, "status":False})
        
    

    def load_toolbtns(self):
        self.pencil_tool = ToolBtns(self, self.pencil_icon, self.pencil_icon_hover, self.pencil_icon_clicked, 5, 5, Tools.pencil)
        self.erase_tool = ToolBtns(self, self.eraser_icon, self.eraser_icon_hover, self.eraser_icon_clicked, 42, 5, Tools.eraser)

    def run(self):
        """ App loop """
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS)
            self.draw()
            self.events()

    def quit(self):
        pg.quit()
        sys.exit()

    def events(self):
        # catch all the events here

        for event in pg.event.get():
            mouse_state = pg.mouse.get_pressed()
            x, y = self.get_tile()
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.quit()

            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # event.button = (left, middle, right, wheel up, wheel down)
                if event.button == 1 and self.selected_tool.tool_type == Tools.pencil:
                    print(x, y)
                    self.register_pixel(x, y, draw=True)
                elif event.button == 1 and self.selected_tool.tool_type == Tools.eraser:
                    print(x, y)
                    self.register_pixel(x, y, draw=False)
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
                
                # mouse_state = Bool(left, middle, right)
                if mouse_state[0] and self.selected_tool.tool_type == Tools.pencil:
                    print(x, y)
                    self.register_pixel(x, y, draw=True)
                if mouse_state[0] and self.selected_tool.tool_type == Tools.eraser:
                    print(x, y)
                    self.register_pixel(x, y, draw=False)

            for btn in self.tool_buttons:

                if btn.rect.collidepoint(pg.mouse.get_pos()):
                    btn.hovered = True
                    if mouse_state[0]:
                        if btn.tool_type != self.selected_tool.tool_type:
                            self.selected_tool.clicked = False
                        self.selected_tool = btn
                        self.selected_tool.clicked = True
                else:
                    btn.hovered = False
                            

    def get_tile(self):
        """ Returns the tile that the mouse is pointing """

        x, y = pg.mouse.get_pos()
        x -= self.canvas.rect.x
        y -= self.canvas.rect.y
        dx = x // self.tile_size
        dy = y // self.tile_size
        if (dx >= 0 and dy >= 0) and (dx <= self.tile_size - 1 and dy <= self.tile_size - 1):
            return (dx, dy)
        return None, None

    def register_pixel(self, x, y, draw=True):
        """ Register new pixels onto the canvas matrix
            Default color is BLACK """
        
        if x is None or y is None:
            return
        try:
            self.canvas_grid[x][y] = {"color":self.selected_color, "status":True} if draw else {"color":None, "status":False}
        except IndexError:
            print("Index Error: out of canvas range")

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(SCREEN_COLOR)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.draw_pixel(self.canvas_grid)
        self.gui.draw()
        self.tool_buttons.update()
        self.tool_buttons.draw(self.screen)
        pg.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    tile_size = int(input("Tile Size >> "))
    p = Pyxel(tile_size)
    p.new()
    while True:
        p.run()
```

#### Canvas file

```
import pygame as pg
from settings import *

class Canvas:

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        self.screen = app.screen
        self.image = pg.Surface((CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT))
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = app.screen_rect.center)

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        self.grid()

    def grid(self):
        for x in range(0, CANVAS_WIDTH, TILESIZE):
            pg.draw.line(self.image, LIGHTGREY, (x, 0), (x, self.rect.bottom))
        for y in range(0, CANVAS_HEIGHT, TILESIZE):
            pg.draw.line(self.image, LIGHTGREY, (0, y), (self.rect.right, y))

    def draw_pixel(self, canvas_data):
        """ Draws pixels on the screen """

        for row, data in enumerate(canvas_data):
            for col, px in enumerate(data):
                if px:
                    if px["status"]:
                        #self.canvas.image.fill(px["color"], pg.Rect(row * self.tile_size, col * self.tile_size, self.tile_size, self.tile_size))
                        pg.draw.rect(self.image, px["color"], pg.Rect(row * self.app.tile_size, col * self.app.tile_size, self.app.tile_size, self.app.tile_size))
```

#### GUI file

```
import pygame as pg
from settings import *
from utils import Tools

class GUI:

    """ This is just the background, for now """

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        self.screen = app.screen
        self.image = pg.Surface((GUI_WIDTH, GUI_HEIGHT))
        self.image.fill(GUI_COLOR)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    #TODO
    def add_btn(self):
        pass

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

class ToolBtns(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, app, base, hover_image, clicked_image, x, y, tool_type: Tools):
        self.groups = app.tool_buttons
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.gui_surface = app.gui.image
        self.gui_rect = app.gui.rect
        self.screen = app.screen

        self.base_image = base
        self.hover_image = hover_image
        self.clicked_image = clicked_image

        self.tool_type = tool_type

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        
        self.image = self.base_image
        self.rect = self.base_image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.gui_rect.x + x
        self.rect.y = self.gui_rect.y + y
        
        self.hovered = False
        self.clicked = False

    def update(self):
        if self.hovered:
            self.image = self.hover_image
        if self.clicked:
            self.image = self.clicked_image
        else:
            self.image = self.base_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.gui_rect.x + self.x
        self.rect.y = self.gui_rect.y + self.y
```

#### Tools file

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class Tools(Enum):

    pencil = auto()
    eraser = auto()
```

#### Settings file

```
# (R, G, B)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
DARKGREY = (129, 129, 129)
LIGHTGREY = (190, 190, 190)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

TITLE = "Pyx"
WIDTH = 1400
HEIGHT = 1400
TILESIZE = 32
FPS = 60

GUI_WIDTH = 100
GUI_HEIGHT = 100
GUI_COLOR = (222, 222, 222)

CANVAS_WIDTH = TILESIZE * TILESIZE
CANVAS_HEIGHT = TILESIZE * TILESIZE
CANVAS_X = int(WIDTH * 0.5)
CANVAS_Y = int(HEIGHT * 0.5)
SCREEN_COLOR = DARKGREY
GRID_COLOR = LIGHTGREY 

# ICONS
PENCIL_ICON = 'pencil_icon.png'
PENCIL_HOVER = 'pencil_icon_hover.png'
PENCIL_CLICKED = 'pencil_icon_clicked.png'
ERASER_ICON = 'eraser_icon.png'
ERASER_HOVER = 'eraser_icon_hover.png'
ERASER_CLICKED = 'eraser_icon_clicked.png'
```

I just posted all my code because It is splitted in several files and I don't want to miss anything important. I hope it isn't too much.

Thanks

Comment: This is a *lot* of code to read through. Can you instead explain in simple terms how the eraser is supposed to work in theory, and show what it's doing instead?

Comment: @RandomDavis Hello, yes I'm sorry. I edited the post to show a video using the app and showing the issue. The eraser tool should erase the existence of a pixel in the canvas area.

Comment: It looks like `draw_pixel` only draws new rectangles; if nothing is being cleared in-between draws, your changes can only be additive.

Comment: An eraser should not change a pixel from "drawn" to "not drawn"  It needs to change the pixels color back to the background.

Comment: @Rabbid76 In main file, in `load_toolbtns` method, the buttons are instantiated. The tool type is passed to the instance as a initialization variable. Then the pencil tool is assigned to `self.selected_tool`

Comment: @TimRoberts the canvas starts out with all pixels set as not drawn. That renders without an issue. The issue is that the draw function doesn't clear out the canvas before drawing pixels, meaning there's no way they can be erased. Setting a pixel to the background color wouldn't be the ideal solution, since then the distinction between a blank pixel and a white/background colored pixel would be lost.

Comment: @RandomDavis If I change this line `pg.draw.rect(self.image, px["color"], pg.Rect(row * self.app.tile_size, col * self.app.tile_size, self.app.tile_size, self.app.tile_size))` from the `draw_pixel` method from Canvas class to `pg.draw.rect(self.screen, px["color"], pg.Rect(row * self.app.tile_size, col * self.app.tile_size, self.app.tile_size, self.app.tile_size))` (notice `self.image` to `self.screen`) the eraser tool works as intended, but outside of the canvas surface. The pixels gets drawn on the screen directly and erased there as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to draw a rectangle in the background color (white) if "status" is False and the field is erased:

```py
class Canvas:
   
    # [...]

    def draw_pixel(self, canvas_data):
        """ Draws pixels on the screen """

        for row, data in enumerate(canvas_data):
            for col, px in enumerate(data):
                if px:
                    color = px["color"] if px["status"] else (255, 255, 255)
                    rect = pg.Rect(row * self.app.tile_size, col * self.app.tile_size, self.app.tile_size, self.app.tile_size)
                    pg.draw.rect(self.image, color, rect)
```

Comment: I got the same result as with my code :/

Comment: Oh, no, I just forgot to erase the `if px["status"]` line! This worked like charm! Thank you Rabbid :)